# Clear PivotItem cache

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I know that you aren't supposed to add more than 7 items to a pivot control, but it's just dead easy to use.

I wasn't even running into problems until now: I got a pivot item template which renders articles (Say, date, title, content). I'm using a pivot because when flicking the article I want to go the next/previous one. However, after a number of flicks (~50, little abyssmal) I get an OutOfMemoryException. The memory usage suggests, that PivotItem contents are generated on the fly when first accessed, but then they aren't released.

I could hook into UnloadedPivotItem/LoadedPivotItem (works well for image viewing and the Source property) and clear the visual trees, but that would mean that I had to generate the contents for every view model "by hand".

So: Is there any possible way to specify how big that cache should be? Or at least a sane way to regenerate the PivotItem content from a given ViewModel?

Comment: Are you using pictures in your pivot items?

Comment: nope, just some text blocks and borders to resemble http://www.readability.com/ 's style. Memory usage rises by 1-2 mb per article depending on content, which is fatal only in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) [SlideView](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/slideview.aspx) control. [In my mind](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2013/08/15/Why-do-you-not-have-Teleriks-Phone-controls-for-yours-Windows-Phone-dev.aspx), there is no reason to not use Telerik's control (I do not work for, nor endorsed by Telerik). You can download the Telerik Examples app from the store to see it being used. This control is exactly what you need. It works just like any other ItemsControl would. You set the ItemsSource and ItemTemplate.

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" 
                    IsLoopingEnabled="False" <!-- Will NOT go back to the beginning -->
                    ItemRealizationMode="ViewportItem">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="12,0,0,0">
                <!-- Content ->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView>
```

Comment: I, too, think that they are really attracting. However, I hoped that I could get around with a simple workaround I (or rather the company) didn't have to pay for, since it's actually quite a bizarre use case and a rather simple app.

Comment: That said; It's not I don't want to pay 99$ for a great set of controls, it's just that I think it will be easier to convince my employer that sliding through 50+ items is a rather rare scenario than get them to pay for the controls.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. I talked to my guy over at the company and he said they own a Telerik license :). So suddenly all my ugly Pivot hacks vanished from code-behind.